# How to create a formula of a sequence that covers all the rational numbers from $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

In beginning of the year in lectures the proffessor written down this sequence:

$$\frac{0}{1},\frac{1}{1},\frac{0}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{2}{2},\frac{0}{3}, \frac{1}{3}$$

So you know what the idea is, I am sure it's a well known thing, but when I searched for it I couldn't find it.

I am also wondering if there exists a sequence that covers all the rational numbers from $(-\infty,\infty)$

Comment: see [cantor paring function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function#Cantor_pairing_function)

Comment: A tweet post https://twitter.com/CompSciFact/status/571079267414626304?s=20